# Close drawer on back press in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am adding flutter to the existing project. In flutter module I have the home page it contains the drawer.but on back press `drawer` is not closing.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: HomePage(),
    drawer: Drawer(),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give `Scaffold` a `GlobalKey` and wrap your widget in `WillPopScope`

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _globalKey = GlobalKey();
...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    key: _globalKey,
    drawer: Drawer(),
    body: WillPopScope(
      child: HomePage(),
      onWillPop: () {
        if (_globalKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
          Navigator.pop(context); // closes the drawer if opened
          return Future.value(false); // won't exit the app
        } else {
          return Future.value(true); // exits the app
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CopsOnRoad answer is great. this's just an updated version
with a nicer way to detect whether the drawer is
opened or not using the `Scaffold` property `onDrawerChanged`

```
bool _drawerIsOpened;
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      onDrawerChanged: (isopened) => _drawerIsOpened = isopened,
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          if (_drawerIsOpened == true) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(); // close the drawer
            return Future.value(false); // don't close the app
          }
          // you can return ShowDialog() here instead of Future true
          return Future.value(true); // close the app
          
        },
```